# How to run all Specs2 tests under IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, specs2

In my Scala project, my Specs2 tests are structured as follows:

```
src/test/scala
-> my.package
---> my.package.sub1
------> SomeTest1
------> SomeTest2
---> my.package.sub2
------> SomeTest3
```

I'm using SBT to build all of this, and I can use `sbt test` to run all tests in my package.

I'd like to use IntelliJ IDEA's built-in Specs2 run configuration support. I point it to use all tests in `my.package`.

Running this yields the error message `Error running <run config name>: Not found suite class.` It cannot find Specs2 test suites. IDEA runs my tests if I point it to a subpackage.

How do I configure IDEA to look in all packages and run all the test suites it finds?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to run all my Specs2 tests in IDEA 13.1.4 and the more recent 14.0.1 using `All in package` for `Test kind` and `In whole project` or `In single module` for `Search for tests`. I left `Test Package` field empty.

[image]

I had to create this configuration manually.

You may want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to create a Specs2 configuration and then modify it accordingly.

Comment: I tried doing this but got a 'Not found suite class' error.  Is there something I have to do in the test code to make this work?  It works from SBT at the command-line.

Comment: @melston, not a solution, but I had the same problem with a project I set up  outside of IntelliJ. When I set up a project for scratch inside InelliJ, I don't have any problems.

Comment: Specs2 IntelliJ integration is flaky: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13603