# Why don't specs2 + scalamock tests run in IntelliJ? Multiple suite traits detected

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-14, scalamock

I'm trying to run Specs2 tests from IDEA from both Windows and Mac versions of Intellij IDEA 14. I generated the idea project files using both `gen-idea` and the built in SBT plugin and get the same results...

When I try to run them, I get

```
Error running Specs2 in 'scala': Test class not found
```

I've added packages and switched "search for tests" to `in single module` but still no avail. I also get the message below on the run config.

```
Multiple suite traits detected: List(ScTrait: SpecificationStructure, ScTrait: SpecificationStructure,)
```

The similar post [How to run all Specs2 tests under IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138104/how-to-run-all-specs2-tests-under-intellij-idea) doesn't help and it all runs fine from SBT, BTW. I can't run individual tests via the short-cut either :'(

I'm suspecting it's a combination of scalamock and specs2, as if I remove the following from my `build.sbt`, I can run them again.

```
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-specs2-support" % "3.2" % "test"
```

Here's the run config.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it in command line to make sure it's all properly configured otherwise?

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned, SBT (from the command line) runs fine...

Comment: You should check if you have multiple specs2 jars dependencies in your module. I had an additional dependency, removed it and the configuration error disappeared.

Comment: Good tip, thanks. That looks like it was it! Do you want to add an answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Comment: To help other googlers, it could also be that you have one package depending on specs2-core, and scalamock-specs2-support which depends on specs2. The solution is to add an explicit dependency on specs2, and both dependencies should be evicted to the one you import. I was just able to fix this with the following dependency: `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "3.7" % "test",`

Comment: @jbrown - this fixed it! I think you should make your comment an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if you have multiple specs2 jars dependencies in your module. If you just leave one jar dependency the configuration error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

To help other googlers, it could also be that you have one package depending on specs2-core, and scalamock-specs2-support which depends on specs2. The solution is to add an explicit dependency on specs2, and both dependencies should be evicted to the one you import. I was just able to fix this with the following dependency: `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "3.7" % "test"`